# Multiple dropdown elimination form using PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am having quite a hard time figuring this out. Basically, its a form with several dropdown menus. The user could select one or multiple items from the dropdowns to help filter out MySQL data results. So I would like to eliminate options as the user fills in the form. So, for example, user selects "Nike" and "Adidas" from the brands menu, all the other dropdown menus should be updated and only show a list that is either related to "Nike" or "Adidas". Let's say the Countries dropdown menu will no longer list all the countries and will instead just show USA (Nike) and Germany (Adidas). And so on and so forth with the other dropdown menus.. Here is the PHP/HTML code.

```
<?php

// Connection
require_once('./db.inc.php');


$brands_list_query = "SELECT DISTINCT brand from inventory ORDER BY brand ASC";
$brands_list_result = mysql_query($brands_list_query) or die('Error, brands listing failed: ' . mysql_error());
$brands_list = "";
while($brands_list_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($brands_list_result)) {
    $brand = $brands_list_row['brand'];
    $brands_list .= "<option value=\"$brand\">$brand</option>\n";
}

$countries_list_query = "SELECT DISTINCT country from inventory ORDER BY country ASC";
$countries_list_result = mysql_query($countries_list_query) or die('Error, countries listing failed: ' . mysql_error());
$countries_list = "";
while($countries_list_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($countries_list_result)) {
    $country = $countries_list_row['country'];
    $countries_list .= "<option value=\"$country\">$country</option>\n";
}

$models_list_query = "SELECT DISTINCT model from inventory ORDER BY model ASC";
$models_list_result = mysql_query($models_list_query) or die('Error, models listing failed: ' . mysql_error());
$models_list = "";
while($models_list_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($models_list_result)) {
    $model = $models_list_row['model'];
    $models_list .= "<option value=\"$model\">$model</option>\n";
}

$shapes_list_query = "SELECT DISTINCT shape from inventory ORDER BY shape ASC";
$shapes_list_result = mysql_query($shapes_list_query) or die('Error, shapes listing failed: ' . mysql_error());
$shapes_list = "";
while($shapes_list_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shapes_list_result)) {
    $shape = $shapes_list_row['shape'];
    $shapes_list .= "<option value=\"$shape\">$shape</option>\n";
}

// Close connection
mysql_close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2/select2.css">  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="select2/select2.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.select_width {
    width: 180px;
}
</style>

<script>
  $(function(){
// turn the element to select2 select style
$('#select1').select2();
$('#select2').select2();
$('#select3').select2();
$('#select4').select2();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form target="browser" method="GET" action="browser.php">

Brands:<br />
<select name="brands[]" id="select1" class="select_width" multiple="multiple">
<?php echo $brands_list; ?>
</select>

</br >

Countries:<br />
<select name="countries[]" id="select2" class="select_width" multiple="multiple">
<?php echo $countries_list; ?>
</select>

</br >

Models:<br />
<select name="models[]" id="select3" class="select_width" multiple="multiple">
<?php echo $models_list; ?>
</select>

</br >

Shapes:<br />
<select name="shapes[]" id="select4" class="select_width" multiple="multiple">
<?php echo $shapes_list; ?>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
  `brand` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shape` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `details` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)
```

How may I go on with this? Will jQuery be needed to update the lists as the user updates the form? Or is there another way?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide information about your database?

Comment: Hello Jon, I just added the MySQL info above. Thanks!

Comment: @JonSurrell, what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: There is significant work to get from where you are now to where you need to be, and I am unable to provide that at this time. However, I'll suggest an offsite resource for learning [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS): [LearnRx](http://reactive-extensions.github.io/learnrx/). Some of the exercises there are similar to what you want to achieve, and if you can find the parallels, it should help you towards a possible solution.

Comment: @JonSurrell, thanks for the input. I will look into it. Here's an example of what I wanted: http://www.hoffmeister.de/en/search/

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick or onchange event on each of those selection boxes to call a js function that would build a url for an iframe on the page.

Since you have multiple selections, you will have to pass an array; something like "inventorySearch.php?brand=Adidas,Nike&country=us,uk&andSoOn".

The php page then builds a query to select from the `inventory` table based on the selection criteria passed in the query string, as in "WHERE brand in('Adidas', 'Nike')..." and fetches from database and displays those in a table.

The tricky parts will be in assembling the querystring (catering for select boxes that have no selections), and the likewise for the WHERE clause of the SQL.

Is that enough to go on?